# Compiling MariaDB Connector v1.0.5 and/or Mysql Connection v 5.3.4

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-connector, unixodbc, slackware

I am trying to compile MariaDB Connector v1.0.5 and/or Mysql Connection v 5.3.4.

I have MariaDB Server v.10.0.21 installed on a Slackware server.  I just need to get a MYSQL connector working, doesn't matter which one.

Also applied the patch mentioned in [Is there compatible ODBC driver with Mariadb 10 on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030590/is-there-compatible-odbc-driver-with-mariadb-10-on-linux)

When I compile the MariaDB Connector I get an error saying "MariaDB not found".

When I compile the Mysql Connector I get the following error:

> - CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
> - Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
>     MYSQL_LIB
>     linked by target "myodbc5a" in directory /downloads/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-src/driver
>     linked by target "myodbc5w" in directory /downloads/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-src/driver
>     linked by target "myodbc5S" in directory /downloads/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-src/setupgui
>     linked by target "myodbc-installer" in directory /downloads/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-src/installer

### OUTOUT from Error File

> Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
>   Change Dir: /downloads/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:/usr/bin/gmake "cmTryCompileExec3523358880/fast"
>   /usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3523358880.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3523358880.dir/build
>   gmake[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030590/is-there-compatible-odbc-driver-with-mariadb-10-on-linux): Entering directory `/downloads/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /downloads/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
>   Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3523358880.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
>   /usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3523358880.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckFunct
>   ionExists.c
>   Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec3523358880
>   /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3523358880.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
>   /usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3523358880.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec3523358880 -rdynamic -lpth
>   reads
>   /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   gmake[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec3523358880] Error 1
>   gmake[1]: Leaving directory`/downloads/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec3523358880/fast] Error 2
>
> Determining if the function dlopen exists failed with the following output:
>   Change Dir: /downloads/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:/usr/bin/gmake "cmTryCompileExec1888052970/fast"
>   /usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1888052970.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1888052970.dir/build
>   gmake[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030590/is-there-compatible-odbc-driver-with-mariadb-10-on-linux): Entering directory `/downloads/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /downloads/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
>   Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1888052970.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
>   /usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=dlopen   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1888052970.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckFunctionExist
>   s.c
>   Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec1888052970
>   /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1888052970.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
>   /usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=dlopen    CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1888052970.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec1888052970 -rdynamic
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1888052970.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o: In function`main':
>   CheckFunctionExists.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `dlopen'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   gmake[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec1888052970] Error 1
>   gmake[1]: Leaving directory`/downloads/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec1888052970/fast] Error 2
>
> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the precompiled versions.  Copy the libraries to the lib and include directories.